# The acceptance checkmark is not visible

Tags: bug, status-norepro, accepted-answer

Even though, I have reinstalled the windows and all the browsers  the acceptance checkmark is  still invisible.

Comment: Screenshot please? And a link to the question (or a question) where you've observed this. Also, information on the browser you're using (and OS), as well as any other visual anomalies you've observed would be helpful.

Comment: Oh, how can I find this information , on the browser etc?  I have observed this problem with each question. For some reason I can't take the screenshot now. That's probably one of the anomalities.

Comment: @Monica It's important that you provide us with more information—if you can tell me which operating system you use (Windows or Mac?) then I can show you how to take a screenshot.

Comment: What kind of IE6 are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows. What is IE6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the logs, you seem to be using Chrome 21 on Windows 7 - but, uh, so am I, and I see the checkmark just fine. The only difference is I'm on the 64-bit flavor of Windows.

It's also possible you're using a different browser, on a different OS, and it's spoofing the user agent - in which case I have no idea what you're using, or what could be going wrong with it.

[image: checkmark]

Until someone can reproduce this, not much I can do I'm afraid. Try a hard refresh: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, Shog9